# Radius of geodesic disc

Tags: differential-geometry

I'm trying to find the radius of a geodesic disc with center (0,0,1) on the paraboloid 
$$ r(u,v) = [\sqrt{1-u} \cos(v), \sqrt{1-u} \sin(v),u] $$ expressed by $u.$

That is, the length of the curve $r(u, 0)$
as a function of $u.$

I have tried computing 
$$\int_u^1 \|\frac{dr}{du} \| du$$ we get this from [wolphram alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+%28sqrt%281+%2B+1%2F%284%2a%28u-1%29%29%29)

This is singular in the at $u = 1$ but is supposed to be 0.

Now I don't know how to proceed further.

Thanks!

Comment: I think you put in $u-1$ rather than $1-u$. But I would seriously recommend parametrizing by $r(u,v)=(u\cos v,u\sin v,1-u^2)$. You still end up with $\int \sec^3\theta\,d\theta$ when you make an obvious substitution.